# How can i manage deployment, installation, upgrade of Android&IOS applications for internal usage on mobil devices?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, application-management

I am developing **Android** and **IOS** mobil applications in **Xamarin**.
These applications will be used in company mobile devices in local network.
Users will make VPN to company network and use these applications internally.
**We dont want to upload these applications to google play or apple store for security reasons.** Only company members will install application.

How can we manage deployment, installation and updates/upgrades of the application for Android/IOS devices in our company.

Comment: For iOS you will need an Enterprise developer program membership. You should use an MDM system to deploy the apps to iOS and Android devices.

Comment: Also consider [Microsoft App Center](https://appcenter.ms/).

Comment: Thanks Steve, let me check